# Mi componente principal no me carga el componente secundario incrustado

Tags: angular

tengo un pequeño problema que me está dando dolor de cabeza

Tengo un componente en esta caso llamado Home y un segundo componente llamado Registrate.

Lo que yo requiero es que ese segundo componente pueda ser usado en home, o en cualquier otro componente y según recuerdo la manera clásica de usarlo era en mi componente principal llamar el componente y con el selector cargarlo

```
<app-registrate></app-registrate>
```

Pero no logro hacer que funcione, dejo un enlace a stackblitz con la estructura básica de lo que tengo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rfnyyb?embed=1&file=src/app/shared/registrate/registrate.component.ts

Espero puedan ayudarme

**EDITO** añadiendo código por si el link llegase a no funcionar:

home.component.html

```
<h1>A simple h1</h1>
<app-registrate></app-registrate>
```

home.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RegistrateModule } from '../../shared/registrate/registrate.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
const homeRoute: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(homeRoute),
    CommonModule,
    RegistrateModule,
  ],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

registrate.component.html

```
<p>Just a text</p>
```

registrate.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RegistrateComponent } from './registrate.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [RegistrateComponent],
  providers: [],
  **exports: [RegistrateComponent],**
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class RegistrateModule {}
```

Y como comentaron en la respuesta aceptada, solo me faltaba añadir el

**exports:[RegistrateComponent]**

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para incluir el código en cuestión. Usar enlaces a sitios externos no es conveniente ni bien recibido.

Comment: @CandidMoe en este enlace [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) mencionan que es aceptable para poder ver la falla, lo que si se me había ido era meter también parte del código, pero aquí dice que es útil
**Si es posible crear un ejemplo vivo del problema al que puedas enlazar (por ejemplo, en http://sqlfiddle.com/ o http://jsbin.com/) entonces hazlo - pero también incluye el mismo código en tu pregunta. No todos pueden acceder a sitios externos, y los enlaces se pueden quebrar con el tiempo.**

Comment: El enlace se refiere a un "ejemplo vivo", es decir, algo ejecutable. La pregunta igual tiene que llevar el código ("pero también incluye el mismo código en tu pregunta"). Por otra parte, tener que ir a mirar el código a un sitio externo quita las ganas de trabajar en la pregunta. Ten eso en mente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te hace falta es exportar el componente en el módulo `RegistrateModule`:

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [CommonModule],
      declarations: [RegistrateComponent],
      exports:[RegistrateComponent],// exportar el componente
      providers: [],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    })
    export class RegistrateModule {}
```

Comment: Era justamente esto, muchas gracias